# Helicopter challenge

Tags: code-golf, number

There is a helicopter flying **500** meters from the ground. It can fly up **100** meters, which takes **1.0 secs**. Or if it doesn't fly up it will fall 200 meters, which also takes **1.0 secs** - This means if the instruction is **anything** other than "Fly" the helicopter falls. Build a program that takes input of a list of instructions, telling the helicopter when to fly and when not to. **When the helicopter falls it should output the time counter**.

INPUT:

> Fly Dance Fly Golf Fly Fly

OUTPUT:

> 8.5 secs

Walkthrough:

> 1) Fly == Fly so +100 = 600m
>
> 2) Dance != Fly so -200 = 400m
>
> 3) Fly == Fly so +100 = 500m
>
> 4) Golf != Fly so -200m = 300m
>
> 5) Fly == Fly so +100 = 400m
>
> 6) Fly == Fly so +100 = 500m
>
> 7) NO INSTRUCTIONS so -200 = 300m
>
> 8) NO INSTRUCTIONS so -200 = 100m
>
> 9) NO INSTRUCTIONS so -100 = 0m (This takes 0.5 seconds)

Each instruction should be separated by a space, and if the instuction isn't fly, then automatically fall. When the program runs out of instructions automatically fall. Your program **must** output in (float)secs, and if it takes  => 60.0 seconds display in mins and seconds eg. 1 mins 32.0 secs

Seconds are float **decimal** values, minutes are whole interger values. Also note capitalization does **not** matter your program should work for capitals or no capitals.

This is code-golf so the least NO bytes wins!

Comment: Could you clarify this? Perhaps a step by step walk through of the example. Is the word "fall" being used both for dropping 200 meters, and for reaching 0 meters? Perhaps using a different word for reaching 0 meters would make this clearer. Is the output the time when the helicopter reaches 0 meters?

Comment: Can we assume that if the helicopter is at 100m, and falls, it still takes 1 second to reach 0m, even though it usually takes 1 second to drop by 200m?

Comment: I think this could be a good question is it is asked more clearly maybe with some examples. May I suggest the Sandbox to get some feedback prior to posting next time?

Comment: `if it dosen't fly up, it will fall 200m` does that mean heli can **crash** and after crashing it should not fly anymore which means rest of the instructions should be ignored? Example : please tell me output if the input is this : `fly fall fall fall fall fly fly fly fly`

Comment: The string `"M min S secs"` specifically, or are normal output formats like a list of `[M,S]` and other reasonable formats like `"M:S"` OK? If specifically, then can less than one minute output `"0 min S secs"`?

Comment: Thankyou all for your feedback, I have edited the question and hope it will be more clear.

Comment: Does input capitalization matter? Can a non-fly instruction contain the string "fly"?

Comment: Still not clear : Mukul's question is important : what is the expected result of "a b c Fly" ? Considering physics, it should be 2.5 cause the helicopter touch the ground before being instructed to fly. Is correct, some answer are already wrong.

Comment: Plus, format constaint does not add fun to the challenge : 61.5 should be acceptable IMHO.

Comment: [Cumbersome IO formats are a thing to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/46076).

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>100</s> <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```
lambda I:sum(reduce(lambda(a,s),i:(a+(a>0)*(-1,.5)[i=='Fly'],s+(a>0)),I.split(),(2.5,0)))
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##ZYxBDoIwEEX3nmKCC6ZaiZKwIcGV0XAGdVGglSalJW1ZcPqKIRGiiz/Jf5P/@tG3RqdBFI@gWFc1DMrcDR1a3gw1x5kho45QmSPbIzsfyQ4PJ5pk5C6LIr6qMX5SN38ILRPXK@mRUEyTjE6IhN5K7VFgFBGy@ZYL0zX/J7C@k/w30wK2UFvmWqi4MJaDt6PUL/AGhBoX3WewaG5GiZUjvAE)

Comment: This doesn't output minutes though.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
l#ā«'¤†Q3*Í5šηO.γd}нRć;sg+60‰0Û
```

Follows the challenge to the letter. Input as a space-delimited string, and output as a list `[sec]` or `[min,sec]`, where `sec` is a float and the potential `min` is an integer.

If taking the input as a list of strings is allowed, the `#` could be removed.
If outputting as `[min,sec]` even if `min` is 0 is allowed, the tailing `0Û` can be removed.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/R/lI46HV6oeWPGpYEGisdbjX9OjCc9v99c5tTqm9sDfoSLt1cbq2mcGjhg0Gh2f//@@WU6ngkpiXnKoAYrnn56SBGUAMAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/HOUjjYdWqx9a8qhhQaCx1uFe06MLz2331zu3OaX2wt6gI@3WxenaZgaPGjYYHJ79X@d/tJJbTqWCS2JecqoCiOWen5Om4OYTqZDmU6mko6AEkUEmQarQMEghCIP1gYRQabBUTmVmXjqIB6WgTJAclDeKR/EoHsY4MS9FobgksahEIS0xJwdUDuTllyvFAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
l                             # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
                              #  i.e. "Fly Dance Fly Golf FLY fLy"
                              #   → "fly dance fly golf fly fly"
 #                            # Split it on spaces
                              #  → ["fly","dance","fly","golf","fly","fly"]
  ā                           # Push a list in the range [1, length]
                              # (without popping the list itself)
                              #  → [1,2,3,4,5,6]
   «                          # Merge it to the list of words
                              #  → ["fly","dance","fly","golf","fly","fly",1,2,3,4,5,6]
    '¤†                      '# Push dictionary string "fly"
       Q                      # Check for each word (or integer) if it's equal to "fly"
                              # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
                              #  → [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        3*                    # Multiply each by 3
                              #  → [3,0,3,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]
          Í                   # Decrease each by 2 (so 1 if truthy; -2 if falsey)
                              #  → [1,-2,1,-2,1,1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2]
           5š                 # Prepend a 5 to this list
                              #  → [5,1,-2,1,-2,1,1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2]
             η                # Get all prefixes of this list
                              #  → [[5],[5,1],...[[5,1,-2,1,-2,1,1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2]]
              O               # Sum each prefix
                              #  → [5,6,4,5,3,4,5,3,1,-1,-3,-5,-7]
               .γ }           # Consecutive group the values by:
                 d            #  Where the value is >= 0
                              #   → [[5,6,4,5,3,4,5,3,1],[-1,-3,-5,-7]]
                }н            # After the group-by, only leave the first group
                              #  → [5,6,4,5,3,4,5,3,1]
                  Rć          # Reverse and extract the head,
                              # so we've extracted the last item loose to the stack
                              #  → [3,5,4,3,5,4,6,5] and 1
                    ;         # Halve that last item
                              #  → [3,5,4,3,5,4,6,5] and 0.5
                     sg       # Swap to get the list, and pop and push its length
                              #  → 8
                       +      # Add it to the halved last item
                              #  → 8.5
                        60‰   # Take the divmod-60
                              #  → [0,8.5]
                           0Û # And remove a potential leading 0
                              #  → [8.5]
                              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `'¤†` is `"fly"`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 90 bytes

```
$a=5;
$_++,$a+=shift=~/Fly/?1:-2 while$a;
$==$_/60;
$_%=60;
say+($=?"$= mins ":"")."$_ secs"
```

Accepts input as command-line parameters.  Run as

```
perl -E '$a=5;$_++,$a+=shift=~/Fly/?1:-2 while$a>0;$==$_/60;$_%=60;say+($=?"$= mins ":" ")."$_ secs"' Fly Dance Fly Fly Golf
```

Starts `$a` at 5, and increases it by 1 every time it finds "Fly", decrements by 2 otherwise.  Keeps going until `$a` is non-positive, and counts how many iterations it took to get there.  `$=` is special and forces its value to be an integer, so `$==$_/60` only takes the integer portion of the division, ignoring the rest.  Everything else is self-explanatory, I feel.

Answer (score 2):

## C 93

**Thanks to @ceilingcat for finding a ***much*** shorter version**

```
i,h=5;main(c,v)int**v;{for(;h>0;)h+=*v[(++i<c)*i]-'ylF'?-2:1;printf("%f secs\n",i-(h<0)*.5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8PW1Do3MTNPI1mnTDMzr0RLq8y6Oi2/SMM6w87AWjND21arLFpDWzvTJllTKzNWV70yx03dXtfIytC6oAioPk1DSTVNoTg1uTgmT0knU1cjw8ZAU0vPVNO69v///245lf9dEvOSU8Es9/ycNDADiAE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 64 bytes

```
wdm{"Fly"=={1}{-2}IE}@5+]q++pa{0.>}TWsa-.j[~2./.+J60./foJ60.*j.-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/PCW3Wsktp1LJ1rbasLZa16jW07XWwVQ7tlBbuyCx2kDPrjYkvDhRVy8rus5IT19P28vMQE8/LR9EaWXp6f7/D9Ss4JKYl5yqAGK55@ekgRlQDAA)

```
wd         # Split into words
m{         # Map
 "Fly"==   # word is "Fly"?
 {1}{-2}IE # If fly 1 else -2
}
@5+]       # Prepend 5.0
q++pa      # Calculate partial sums
{0.>}TW    # Take until 0 or less
sa-.       # Length of this -1 (to account for pushed 5.0)
j[~2./     # Take the remaining height /2
.+         # Add this time 
############ Mins Secs ##############
J60./fo    # Calc number of mins 
J60.*      # N mins * 60
j.-        # Calc seconds over
```

If we don't have to deal with the mins/secs rule:

## Burlesque, 49 bytes

```
wdm{"Fly"=={1}{-2}IE}@5+]q++pa{0.>}TWsa-.j[~2./.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/PCW3Wsktp1LJ1rbasLZa16jW07XWwVQ7tlBbuyCx2kDPrjYkvDhRVy8rus5IT19P@/9/oGoFl8S85FQFEMs9PycNzIBiAA)

Comment: Incorrect. Consider case `Eat Play Love Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly`. Correct answer is `2.5`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
for($h=5;$h>0;)$h+='Fly'==$argv[++$i]?:-2;echo$h/2+$i;
```

Loops through command line arguments; run with `-r`.

Height is divided by 100 to simplify output and calculation: If height is below zero (i.e. -100m),
adding half of it (-50 divided by 100: -.5) to the time removes half a second from the result.

That combined with the magic of Elvis golfed <s>5</s> 6 bytes from my initial program.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 211 bytes

```
(s=ToString;t=Length[#[[;;(FirstPosition[#,x_/;x<=0,1]-1/. 0->Length@#)]]]&[x=500+Accumulate[If[#=="Fly",100,-200]&/@(StringSplit@#)]];
If[#>=60,s@Floor[#/60]~~" min ",""]~~s@Mod[#,60]~~ " sec"&[t+x[[t]]/200.])&
```

This algorithm assumes the flight ends when the altitude reaches 0 for the first time.  Looking at some of the other answers, I think people have the helicopter flying below ground level. I don't allow "touch and go" either.

Ungolfed:

```
in="Fly Dance Fly Golf Fly Fly";
s=ToString;StringSplit@in
If[#=="Fly",100,-200]&/@%
altList=500+Accumulate@%
l=Length@altList
(* find last positive before first nonpositive *)
FirstPosition[altList,x_/;x<=0,1]-1
t=Length[altList[[;;(%/. 0->l)]]]
t+altList[[t]]/200.
If[%>=60,s@Floor[%/60]~~" min ",""]~~s@Mod[%,60]~~ " sec"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 80 bytes

Caveat: case sensitive.

This will return (minutes, seconds) if the flight takes more than 59 seconds, otherwise – only seconds.

```apl
{(1+⍵≥60)⌷⍵(⍵(⌊÷,⊢|⊣)60)},{(⍵⍳0)⌊¯0.5+⍵⍳¯1}{5++\¯2@~(4×≢⍵)↑{⍵≡'Fly'}¨' '(≠⊆⊢),⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhGoNQ@1HvVsfdS41M9B81LMdyNYA456uw9t1HnUtqnnUtVgTKFerUw2SeNS7GaSu69B6Az1TbYjAofWGtdWm2toxh9YbOdRpmBye/qhzEVBK81HbxGqw4QvV3XIq1WsPrVBXUNd41LngUVcb0GhNHaBkLdAdCuqO6lxAEqQISiu4JOYlpyqAWO75OWlgBkzaNbFEISAnsVLBJ78sFSaDjuEGDVYM9qA6AA)

Without conversion to minutes it's 54 bytes:

```apl
{(⍵⍳0)⌊¯0.5+⍵⍳¯1}{5++\¯2@~(4×≢⍵)↑{⍵≡'Fly'}¨' '(≠⊆⊢),⍵}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 137

```
a=>{for(s=5,i=0,a=a.toLowerCase().split(" ");s>=0;){s+=a[i]&&a[i++]=="fly"?1:-2}return parseInt(i/60)+"min "+(i%60+s/2).toFixed(1)+"sec"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7dasMwDIVfxRhWbNykaWG9WHF3MQgM8gJl9EJN7MzDs4PlLCulz56ZsR9C93PxCSEdnaMneAGsg@lidoCDspnzjRq1HEFuT9oHhvJ6bmQxBwl59JUfVLgDVIzn2FkTGSWUb3Ariw0/oZDwYPazWapC7KWk2h7p7fImW52Din1wpIOA6t5FZhbrggv6bByhgpmrdSFwseIpozSvqmHLtERV0/NYe4feqtz6lmlGS3sk@g8eDYkKY@r7r9nPN/07ZbX7R/dNA65WBFpIXzs/XGqqS/@p7@6D6V3rJ/LfGFLsp4ZyPr4B)

Test:

```
"Fly fly fly fly fly fly fly fly hi test flu fly fly Fly fly fly fly fly flu flu FLY fly fly Fly fly fly fly fly fly fly fly dance again now fly fly fly fly fLy fly fly flu flu fly Fly fly flY flY fly fly fly fly go flu flu fly fly fly fly fly fly fly win flu fly "
```

Result:

```
1min 17.5sec
```

Answer (score -1):

## Python 2, <s>85</s> 91 bytes

```py
t=2.5+input().upper().split().count('FLY')*1.5
print('%d mins'%(t/60))*(t>59),`t%60`,'secs'
```

Takes input on STDIN, surrounded by quotes (single or double). Simply counts the number of `Fly`s there are in the input, performs some path to calculate the number of seconds, then formats it.

Now case-insensitive!

*Fixed a bug with the same bytecount thanks to Jonathan Allan!*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Shebang!*

Comment: Bit of a nitpick, but `"Marty McFly went to the future"` would print `4.0 secs` rather than `2.5 secs`. Fixable for one byte with `t=(5+input().split().count('Fly')*3)/2.`

Comment: ...but you can golf that cost off with `t=2.5+input().split().count('Fly')*1.5`.

Comment: Since I don't think leading spaces matter, this print statement should work: `print('%d mins'%(t/60))*(t>59),``t%60``,'secs'` (replace double ticks with single ticks). It only has a leading space if `t < 60`.

Comment: Also this would return a float for the minutes if it's a float above 60, i.e. `80.5 secs -> 1.3416666 minutes`.

Comment: @Shebang It doesn't return a float for the minutes. The `%d` implicitly casts to an int -- http://ideone.com/JKOS0H. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. Consider the test case `Eat Play Love Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly`. Correct answer is `2.5`.

Answer (score -1):

## Scala, 88 bytes

```
s=>{val n=s.split(" ").count("Fly"==)*1.5+2.5
(if(n<60)""else n/60+"min ")+n%60+" secs"}
```

Ungolfed:

```
s=>{
  val n=s.split(" ").count("Fly"==)*1.5+2.5
  (
    if(n<60)
      ""
    else
      (n/60)+"min "
  )
  +(n%60)
  +" secs"
}
```

Uses the same formula as [Copper's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100110/46901).

Comment: It's incorrect. Consider the test case `Eat Play Love Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly`. Correct answer is `2.5`.

Answer (score -1):

## AWK, 150 bytes

Below is a rather straightforward implementation in AWK,
the nice thing about it is that you can run it interactively and
feed it by typing commands by hand (just don't forget to remove RS=" ", if you want one command per line).

**Golfed**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" ";h=500;t=0}toupper($0)~/FLY/{h+=100;t+=1;next}{h-=200;t+=1;}END{t+=h/200;F=(t>59?"%d mins ":"%.0d") "%.1f secs";printf F,t/60,t%60;}'
```

**Test**

```
echo "Fly Dance FLy Golf Fly Fly" |\
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" ";h=500;t=0}toupper($0)~/FLY/{h+=100;t+=1;next}{h-=200;t+=1;}END{t+=h/200;F=(t>59?"%d mins ":"%.0d") "%.1f secs";printf F,t/60,t%60;}'

8.5 secs
```

Comment: Incorrect. Consider case `Eat Play Love Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly Fly`. Correct answer is 2.5 sec.